# Copy from one image to another in Javascript/HTML5

Tags: javascript, html, image, copy

I have an Image holding the map of a country. Now I need to copy a small part of it (a city) to another Image, so as to calculate how many pixels that city occupies (using a Flood Fill algorithm). I know the Canvas element has the drawImage method, I need something similar to copy from one Image to the other, no canvas involved. Is this possible? Or I'll have to create a canvas to do that?

Comment: in order to apply flood fill, u need the pixel information. And the only way for u to examine pixel is through the use of canvas. I doubt there is any alternative.

Comment: @Mox If you're right, then that's the answer. Thank you!